# Avoid resetting HikariCP datasource connection pool on property change/refresh

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, configserver

I am using spring boot 2 with PCF config server to use centrallized config. My microservice is basic crud rest service. What I noticed is that whenever a property is being changed and http post is being made on "actuator/refresh" endpoint, spring boot 2 drops all connection including active ones and rebuilds the connection pool. How can I avoid this? I am also using spring-boot-starter amqp and cloud bus to notify all my service instance to refresh the properties so it is also happening for http post on "actuator/bus-refresh".

Also to clarify, I didnot change any property related to datasource config, instead I am changing application specific property, so why does spring boot refreshing datasource, I did not understood.

Comment: Can you try setting `spring.cloud.refresh.refreshable=""`?

Comment: I do not see this property you mentioned in Finchley release https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.RELEASE/multi/multi__appendix_compendium_of_configuration_properties.html